# Change DataGrid Cell Font when column data has a match in other rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to find a good example of how to change the cell font af a WPF DataGrid when a value is the same for a column in 2 or more rows.

For example, look at the following data:

```
Name, Age
---------
John, 21
John, 35
Doug, 15
```

The name and age would be in different columns in the DataGrid.

I would like the two Johns to display in blue italics and Doug would be the font for all the other cells in the grid. I have looked at using custom converters for setting the cell style but it seems like they only know the value of the current cell. It needs to format the cell based on other cells in the same column. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this or have an example of doing something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using font, I have chosen to use an Icon instead. This was much simpler. If anyone knows of an easy way to accomplish this with fonts, I would love to hear it.